# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-imageview

Tengo un problema con mi código, me aparece el siguiente error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference

Estoy realizando una consulta a una BDSqlite para mostrar los datos en un listview. Como también se van a mostrar imágenes en cada elemento de la lista estoy obteniendo el id del recurso de cada imagen para agregarselo al Imageview. En el Layout principal se encuentra el listview y en otro layout se encuentra el diseño de cada elemento de la lista.
A lo que he investigado el error es por que estoy manejando un Imageview de otro layout, pero no logro dar con la solución. Gracias por sus respuestas.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper conn;
    ListView listViewRadios;
    ArrayList<Radio> arrayList;
    Adaptador adaptador;
    ImageView imgLogo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listViewRadios = findViewById(R.id.listviewRadios);
        conn = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        imgLogo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logo_radio);
        setContentView(R.layout.elemento_lista);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();
        db.close();

        CargarDatosEnListview();
    }

    private void CargarDatosEnListview() {

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM radios",null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){

            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String nombre = cursor.getString(1);
            String uri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("LOGO"));
            int resId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
            imgLogo.setImageResource(resId);
            System.out.println("Esto es lo que es uri: "+uri);
            System.out.println("Esto es lo que es resId: "+resId);
            String logo = cursor.getString(2);
            String link = cursor.getString(3);
            String favorito = cursor.getString(4);

            Radio radio = new Radio (id,nombre,logo,link,favorito);
            arrayList.add(radio);

        }
        adaptador = new Adaptador(this,arrayList);
        listViewRadios.setAdapter(adaptador);
        adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Si todos los datos que estás obteniendo los guardas en un objeto de la clase `Radio` y luego le pasas al adaptador la lista de radios, por qué no haces la asignación en el adapter, que es donde debe ir?? Para eso estás usando el `Adaptador`. Además, te invito a que mires cómo funcionan los [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview?hl=es-419) que van mucho mejor que los ListView.

Comment: Pues, ese es básicamente tu problema. Dices que en tu `layout` principal solo tienes un `ListView` y en otro `Layout` tu diseño de lo que va dentro de cada item de la lista. Entonces, simplemente debes quitar ese `imgLogo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logo_radio);` o ponerlo debajo de esta línea: `setContentView(R.layout.elemento_lista);` porque estas llamando algo en el layout principal que no existe pero existe en tu otro layout. Fijate poniéndolo debajo de tu segundo layout

Answer (score 1):

El `ImageView` con id `logo_radio` debe encontrarse en `activity_main.xml` de otra forma no podrás modificar sus propiedade, ya que ahí es donde obtienes la referencia.

```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   ...
   ...
   imgLogo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logo_radio);
```

Agrega el `ImageView` en `activity_main.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Posible solución, invierte la ubicación ya que estas llamando a un `ImageView` que no existe en tu `R.layout.activity_main` pero existe en tu `R.layout.elemento_lista`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.elemento_lista);//debes poner esto primero ya que de lo contrario no encontrará tu imageview
imgLogo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logo_radio);
```